# How to pytest python AWS CDK VPC from_lookup

Tags: python, pytest, aws-cdk

When using a stack that gets a VPC using the [`from_lookup`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2/Vpc.html#aws_cdk.aws_ec2.Vpc.from_lookup) method, running unit tests will fail unless you setup credentials, which is not desirable and practical

How can a pytest be written to cope for this?

Example stack module `ec2_stack.py`

```py
# Deps
from aws_cdk import (
    Stack,
    aws_ec2 as _ec2,
)
from constructs import Construct


class Ec2Test(Stack):
    """
    An EC2 test
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        scope: Construct,
        construct_id: str,
        **kwargs,
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)
        self.vpc_id = self.node.try_get_context("vpc_id")
        self.inst_type = self.node.try_get_context("inst_type")
        self.base_ami_id = self.node.try_get_context("base_ami_id")

        self._vpc = _ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(
            scope=self,
            id="my-vpc",
            vpc_id=self.vpc_id,
        )
        self._machine_image = _ec2.MachineImage.generic_linux(
            {"ap-southeast-2": self.base_ami_id}
        )
        self.__create_instance()

    def __create_instance(self):
        """
        Create EC2 instance resource
        """
        _ec2.Instance(
            self,
            "ec2",
            instance_type=_ec2.InstanceType(self.inst_type),
            vpc=self._vpc,
            machine_image=self._machine_image,
        )
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One solution is to use a fixture and add an optional parameter to pass an IVpc object, until mocking libraries are written for CDK ([moto](http://docs.getmoto.org/en/latest/) exists to mock boto3, but couldn't find a CDK equivalent)

Stack constructor update

```py
    def __init__(
        self,
        scope: Construct,
        construct_id: str,
        vpc: _ec2.IVpc = None,  # New parameter
        **kwargs,
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)
        self.vpc_id = self.node.try_get_context("vpc_id")
        self.inst_type = self.node.try_get_context("inst_type")
        self.base_ami_id = self.node.try_get_context("base_ami_id")
        if vpc is not None:
            # Now VPC can be provided optionally
            self._vpc = vpc
        else:
            self._vpc = _ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(
                scope=self,
                id="my-vpc",
                vpc_id=self.vpc_id,
            )
        self._machine_image = _ec2.MachineImage.generic_linux(
            {"ap-southeast-2": self.base_ami_id}
        )
        self.__create_instance()
```

Example pytest code: `test_ec2_stack_vpc.py`

```py
# deps
import aws_cdk as _cdk
from aws_cdk import (
    assertions as assertions,
    aws_ec2 as _ec2,
)
from constructs import Construct
import pytest

from ec2_stack import Ec2Test

EXPECTED_VPC = "vpc-123"
EXPECTED_INST_TYPE = "t3.micro"
EXPECTED_AMI_ID = "ami-123"

TEST_CONTEXT_EC2 = {
      "inst_type": EXPECTED_INST_TYPE,
      "vpc_id": EXPECTED_VPC,
      "base_ami_id": EXPECTED_AMI_ID,
}


@pytest.fixture
def make_vpc():
    def _make_vpc(scope, id):
        return _ec2.Vpc.from_vpc_attributes(
            scope,
            id,
            availability_zones=["ap-southeast-2"],
            vpc_id=EXPECTED_VPC,
            private_subnet_ids=["subnet-9876"],
            private_subnet_names=["priv-8"],
        )

    return _make_vpc


class EmptyStack(_cdk.Stack):
    """
    Stack only to provide context
    """

    def __init__(
        self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, vpc: _ec2.IVpc = None, **kwargs
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)


def test_ec2_created(make_vpc):
    app = _cdk.App(context=TEST_CONTEXT_EC2)
    e_stack = EmptyStack(app, "empty-stack")
    test_vpc = make_vpc(e_stack, "test-vpc")
    stack = Ec2Test(app, "ec2-stack", vpc=test_vpc)
    template = assertions.Template.from_stack(stack)

    template.has_resource_properties(
        "AWS::EC2::Instance", {"InstanceType": EXPECTED_INST_TYPE}
    )
```

Comment: This is a bad testing method. The tested stack has no control over the vpc settings - if the controlling stack of the vpc changes, this test - being mocked - will still pass, but the system may no longer work - but your tests still pass and therefor deployment wouldnt be stopped despite it potentially being a system breaking bug. Mocking is great for things controlled *within* the scope of your test but not for things outside it. There you need contracts and actually reaching out to check that it is still the same before deployment - see my answer for more details

Comment: I disagree, see comment in your answer which does not answer the question, you cannot run pytest without credentials if you depend on lookup result.

Comment: [Pytest mock](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/monkeypatch.html) was created exactly for this kind of testing: "Sometimes tests need to invoke functionality which depends on global settings or which invokes code which cannot be easily tested such as network access.". I only did it differently due to the nature of CDK objects and running without credentials for only testing of the stack code, no integration testing.

Comment: I do not disagree that you would need to mock in order to bypass the need for credentials. What i disagreed with was the methodology in this particular case - Mocking this and then testing the *Values* of that vpc would result in tests passing when the actual prod environment *would not pass* if the stack/app/org controlling the vpc makes changes to those values.  This is not a valid test then, as it does not stop you from deploying without breaking.

Answer (score -1):

I think that perhaps you are considering this from the wrong angle:

The `from` methods assume that the resource exists during synth, and generate a token that will correspond with the right values once CloudFormation is handed the synth'd template and resolves all the things it needs to to import the various resources imported in `from` methods.

In addition, when you are Unit testing CDK, what you are actually doing is just verifying that the template contains the resources you want it to contain, with certain configurations. Importing a resource such as VPC it will have whatever values it has when it was generated by whatever process generates it (another stack, an org level set up functionality, whatever). As such, mocking it and testing for it to have specific values in the stack that is importing it is folly - that could change at any time, and your tests would be reporting that it still passes because your mock value will not have changed even though the actual resource did.

So, you should:

1. Test that your resources that need VPC access have VPC properties set on them. They may resolve to tokens or they may not be 100% clear, but you can have faith that the `from` method will generally work as described and will add the proper values at deployment - you do not have to test that it does, because the CDK teams already do. - You are not testing the *values* here, but just that the given properties exist on a resource and they are not None/empty/null.
2. Then, depending on the nature of how your VPC is created:

   - If you control the VPC in another stack, then you unit test it there for its specific values.  As long as you and your team understand that changing tests once established is *bad* (and if you find that you are doing it a lot, then your code needs to be changed to be more unit testable, not your tests) then you can be reasonably confident that everything will work as expected
   - If you do not control the vpc at all (say using the default or your org has created vpcs in each of its sub accounts for example) then you'll need higher level tests than Unit tests - Integration/Contract testing and health check tests (ie - tests where its OK to have credentials to check on things).

The From Methods, when cdk deploy is used or the CloudFormation deployment initializes from a CodeDeploy are "basically" (generalization incoming) just using the existing SDK methods (ie: like boto3) to get this information at deploy time. The SDKs are just built on top of `aws cli` sdk anyways,  and that is pretty much what every internal resource uses to get information from others it needs at run time as well.

Because these methods are built ins from the CDK teams (and the SDK teams) you do not have to test that they import as expected from things outside the scope of the current test (the vpc is not created during the scope of this test, so it is outside its scope) because you can have faith that AWS is going to do the best they can to make sure it continues to operate as expected. (bugs obviously happen but generally, yes) - after all - you don't go testing that every import worked, right? or that every library that you install that its documented functionally works as expected in isolation (not as part of your behavior) right? `from` methods are the same thing.

Comment: The `fromLookup` methods actually resolve during synth and return the actual values, not tokens.

Comment: The goal is to test the cdk code, which is creating a stack that will try to reuse a VPC, not create one. Therefore mocking a VPC is valid, I am only interested in testing the stack creates the thing expected.

Comment: You should read the [CDK assertions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.assertions.html) module to understand the only point in testing in CDK, that will answer most of the questions you added in your answer.

Comment: @gshpychka my mistake it very much does... however ... i think this is only after a successful connection with credentials, all other times the value are stored in cdk.context.json - so if for the original poster they do not want to have credentials to perform tests then it would still not help them, no?

Comment: You only need credentials once, as you say. After that the cached value will be used, including during tests.